# Using local database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have some problem. I am writing program to control company's budjet. I use two server databases: financeDB and EmployeesDB. But users should be able to use this soft without connection to server, for example at home. So I have a question: how I can provide connection to local DB withont SQL Server installed on PC. I have exception, that programm cann't connect to server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless `MS SQL Server` is locally installed, MS SQL Server is not portable. Use `SQL Server Compact` if you want a portable app that needs functionalities similar to `MS SQL Server`.

Here is the link to the product -

[SQL Server Compact...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142)

It is free and can be downloaded from MS Downloads.

Comment: But there are a lot of programms which use databases. What about them? If user don't have sql server, how this programms connect to DB?

Comment: There are also SQLLite. But the queries are not similar to MS SQL server.

Comment: And what do you recomend to use? It is problem to instal sql server on every PC. There are about 50 users and I don't have possibility to instal server on every PC. To say nothing of memory which server use.

Comment: I already said, use SQL Server Compact, or use LocaDB. Here is a article on their benefits - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx.

Comment: But the benefits of SQL Compact is that you can keep all your MS SQL Queries, there are some differences though, some features are not supported, you can read about them here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(v=sql.110).aspx